# Soundcloud: Can I pull a full list of users who follow a user?

Tags: soundcloud

Looking to pull a full list of users who follow an artist on Soundcloud. I'm currently using the [[/users/{id}/followers]](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users) endpoint and am able to retrieve ~8200 followers of a given handle which is equivalent to limit + offset. Is there a way to go deeper for artists that have more than 8,000 followers? I'm making this call below and paging through the response until there are no more `"next_hrefs"`

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{id}/followers?

```
client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&limit=199&linked_partitioning=1
```